# Extract multiple from html

Tags: php, html, regex, xml, dom

I'm trying to extract the words within the `<li>` `</li>` tags below. My regex is working well, but only giving me the first `<li>`, `Lorem ipsum...`

I'm reasonably new to regex, and I am aware it would be likely more reliable to do this by traversing the DOM, but in this case regex is prefered. Any ideas what I need to change to get all the results, instead of just the one?

`/<div class="foo-bar">[\s\S]+<ul>[\s\S]*?(<li>([\s\S]*?)<\/li>)+[\s\S]*?<\/ul>/`

```
<div class="foo-bar">
    <!-- Other junk -->
    <ul>
        <li>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </li>
        <li>
            Vestibulum iaculis nibh ac orci imperdiet ultrices.
        </li>
        <li>
            Fusce neque lacus, feugiat eget sapien eget, ullamcorper rutrum mauris.
        </li>
        <li>
            Maecenas in ipsum consectetur, finibus ex et, condimentum turpis.
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Other junk -->
</div>
```

Comment: What does your PHP code look like?

Comment: Don't use regex. Use a parser. http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php To do it with regex you'd need to pull the full `ul` then parse out each `li`.

Comment: Doesn't exist yet, just prototyping the regex. Need to fiddle just a snippet as above.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @TomWilsonFL "While it is true that asking regexes to parse arbitrary HTML is like asking Paris Hilton to write an operating system, it's sometimes appropriate to parse a limited, known set of HTML."

Comment: I have read it also. :) I still think it is apt for your question because you may be asking a single Regex to do too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DOM+Xpath not RegEx.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach($xpath->evaluate('//div[@class="foo-bar"]/ul/li') as $li) {
  var_dump($li->textContent);
}
```

Output:

```
string(80) "
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        "
string(75) "
            Vestibulum iaculis nibh ac orci imperdiet ultrices.
        "
string(95) "
            Fusce neque lacus, feugiat eget sapien eget, ullamcorper rutrum mauris.
        "
string(89) "
            Maecenas in ipsum consectetur, finibus ex et, condimentum turpis.
        "
```

Comment: Great answer otherwise though.

Comment: I did. You might not WANT to use an XML parser, but it is the much better solution. So I posted the answer more for others that might have the same problem and find your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add the global `g` flag at the end. For example:

```
/<div class="foo-bar">[\s\S]+<ul>[\s\S]*?(<li>([\s\S]*?)<\/li>)+[\s\S]*?<\/ul>/g
```

You may also want the `i` flag for case-insensitive

Comment: There is no `g` in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php The functions are global or not.

Comment: @chris85 instead of `g` you can use the `preg_match_all()` function

Comment: @funilrys Yea,  `The functions are global or not.` There still is no `g` modifier though.

Comment: @funilrys Yup `preg_match_all()` still only matches one. :(

Comment: @Eamonn Yes, this isn't the answer. The regex won't work as you want.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. If you just want the data between the `<li>`s, could you not just use `\(<li>([\s\S]*?)<\/li>)+\i`

Comment: Yes, but other `<li>` exist in the document, thus needing the `<div class="foo-bar">` wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be better to use the following with `preg_match_all()`. I just tested it [here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) and it's working.

First `preg_match_all` the following to get only the content of the `

```
/<div class="foo-bar">([\s\S]*?)+<ul>([\s\S]*?)<\/ul>([\s\S]*?)<\/div>/
```

Then `preg_match_all` the result of the previous `preg_match_all` with the following to only get the `<li>` contents

```
/<li>([\s\S]*?)<\/li>/
```

Comment: This is what I need, but it also needs the `<div class="foo-bar">` and `<ul>` wrappers to stop it matching other things.

Comment: @Eamonn This, I believe, is impossible in a single Regex. Break it into two Regexps?

Comment: Looks like that's going to be the solution. If you want to update your answer to that I'll accept it.

Comment: @Eamonn Edited my answer can you test it ?